# WSO2 android source code installation in studio

Tags: wso2, mdm

I am trying to install wso2 source code from github to android studio,but i am facing some errors,so please help me step by step method to solve the same
Thanks in Advance

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: Could you please list down the errors so that we can assist you. :)

Comment: hey guys thanks for responding while running the code i am getting the following error in logcat

Comment: I have mentioned my error in answer,sry wrongly posted dont know how to solve it,please check and help

Answer (score 1):

Please follow all the instructions here https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM220/Customizing+the+Android+APK+File

You need to enable Android hidden APIs before compiling the app

Comment: I have already tried the link which you gave still didnt not work, should i change the api level from 16 to 23 in build gradle for this

Comment: compileSdkVersion should be set to 23 and add android hidden API 23 to your platforms/android-23 folder in Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\parvathi\Desktop\CodeMDM\client\client\src\main\java\org\wso2\emm\agent\api\RuntimeInfo.java
Error:(159, 38) error: cannot find symbol method getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory()
C:\Users\parvathi\Desktop\CodeMDM\client\client\src\main\java\org\wso2\emm\agent\services\AlarmReceiver.java
Error:(56, 36) error: cannot find symbol method getExtra(String)
C:\Users\parvathi\Desktop\CodeMDM\client\client\src\main\java\org\wso2\emm\agent\services\NetworkConnectedReceiver.java
Error:(42, 28) error: cannot find symbol method startServiceAsUser(Intent,UserHandle)
C:\Users\parvathi\Desktop\CodeMDM\client\client\src\main\java\org\wso2\emm\agent\utils\CommonUtils.java
Error:(432, 11) error: cannot find symbol method startServiceAsUser(Intent,UserHandle)
Error:(445, 11) error: cannot find symbol method startServiceAsUser(Intent,UserHandle)
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:client:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':client:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.